# Taking input from the user in PYTHON

Tags: python, input

I've been trying to take the input in this format

Input:

```
POSITION 0,0,EAST
```

I want every input stored separately.

The code I've written is:

```
position,x,y,z = list(input().split(','))
```

Can someone help me to find me what is wrong with my input function?

I'm trying to store the input something like this

```
position = 'POSITION'
x = '0'
y = '0'
z = 'EAST'
```

Comment: Can't you change your input to ``POSITION,0,0,EAST``? Note the ``,`` between POSITION and 0, since you're splitting at ``,``. Otherwise, you should use more splits or you could move to regex.

Comment: No, I can't change the input format. I'm just checking if there is any way without using regex. :( ('Cuz I'm very bad at Regex)

Comment: So first split with `split(' ')` and then split the second element of that result with `split(',')`.

Comment: is it that input always start with `'POSITION '`? Is it possible to have more than one space in the input?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a comma after "POSITION" and so your code doesn't execute as expected. If you use this as input `POSITION,0,0,EAST`, your code will execute as expected.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the format as your input, simply split on a comma or a space:

```
import re
position,x,y,z = list(re.split(r'[, ]',input()))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! Can you explain the r'[, ] if you don't mind?

Comment: The starting `r` defines a raw-string where a backslash character is not escaped. In this case we don't need it, but if often comes in handy when working with regular expressions. The `[, ]` is the regular expression used for `re.split`. It defines a group of characters between the square brackets and here these are either the comma or a space.

Answer (score 0):

Because the input cannot be changed, the split(',') will keep the 'POSITION 0' as 1 value.
so you just need to split it again with a space between then with split(' ')
notice that data[0] = 'POSITION 0', data[1] = 0, data[2] = EAST.

```
data = list(input().split(','))
position = data[0].split(' ')[0]
x = data[0].split(' ')[1]
y = data[1]
z = data[2]
print(position + " " + x + " " + y + " " + z)
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work for ``POSITION 0,0,EAST`` as I already stated in my comment above. Did you even try your answer?

Comment: it doesn't work because you don't have a comma after the 'POSITION'

Try: POSITION, 0,0,EAST

Comment: OP said that the input format cannot be changed.

Comment: oh sorry, I will change my code, I thought I saw POSITION,0,0,EAST but it was the first comment to your question.

Comment: It seems you are confused who asked the original question and who wrote a comment, asking for more details. ``BIPIN CHANDRA`` is the OP and asked about ``POSITION 0,0,EAST`` - in a comment I asked the OP if the input format can be changed to ``POSITION,0,0,EAST`` to which OP replied  ``No``.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed, well I will fix my code, even thought thornejosh already wrote a good answer using re.

Answer (score 0):

Your input function you are splitting with `,` as delimiter. If you can change input to `POSITION,0,0,EAST` then your code will work.

If you cannot change the input format then you can replace space with `,` and then split.

```
position,x,y,z=input().replace(" ",",").split(",")
```